# Using Redux to display a notification in response to a network request

Tags: reactjs, redux, getuikit

My web application uses React and Redux and UIKit.
It consists of screens A and B.

Screen A contains a button which - upon pressing - will send an asynchronous network request to post some data to a server.

If a user remains on screen A until a response returns from the server, they will receive confirmation about whether or not the request was successful.

The way I have implemented this using React and Redux is by having a component which is responsible for displaying a confirmation banner. This component listens to changes to a state called `postStatus` in my Redux store. When the user clicks on the button, 3 Redux actions with statuses `PENDING`, `SUCCESS` and `ERROR` are potentially dispatched. After they are dispatched - they are caught by the reducers which change the `postStatus` state accordingly. This state then gets mapped to my components properties and it is re-rendered to display a relevant banner.

However, if the user does not remain on screen A until a response returns from the server and navigates to screen B instead - I would like a [notification](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/notify.html) to show up so the user is still aware of the status of the request.

My question is, what would be the most sensible way to implement this behaviour?

Here are a couple of things I can think of:

1. Create a react component that doesn't actually render anything - it just listens to `postState` and some extra piece of state that represents which screen the user is on. Implement the `componentWillReceiveProps` react lifecycle method and if the `postState` is `SUCCESS` or `ERROR` and the other state says that the user is on not on screen A - then call `UIKit.notify()` to show the notification.
2. Call `UIKit.notify()` when dispatching the `SUCCESS` or `ERROR` action if the user is not on screen A.
3. Call `UIKit.notify()` when reducing the state after being dispatched the `SUCCESS` or `ERROR` action if the user is not on screen A.

There are most likely a lot of other solutions so I'm keen to hear some.

Comment: Method 1 seems better！

Comment: I agree with method 1. Better handling all UI rendering in components whether they return html or not on render().

Comment: Yes but after some research I have found that react components that do not render anything can be considered a misuse of the React library so I'm not sure about using method 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I am late for the answer, but I stumbled upon this myself so here is what I did.

The way I look at it is that the temporary notification is an application side effect.
In my project I am using [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), but you can achieve this using any other side effects library.

The code (using deleting an user as an example):

```
...
function* deleteUserSuccess(action) {
    yield call(message.success, 'Successful deletion!');
}

const watchDeleteUserSuccess = function* () {
    yield takeEvery(types.DELETE_USER_SUCCESS, deleteUserSuccess);
}
...
```

**PROS**: It is readable and it works.

**CONS**: The only downside that I see is that you make your sagas know about your UI library. But you can wrap it in a separate function/file/module to abstract the saga from it.